# if else condition in Regex c# and return constant value

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, c#-4.0

```
string str="abc"

if(str=="abc")
  return "abc";
else
  return "xyz"
```

Can we achieve this in C# Regex. Or another condition is, if input string length is 3 return "abc" otherwise return "xyz"

Comment: What are you testing? Your code sample checks for identity, your question only considers string length.

Comment: Regex does not return anything, it either matches a string or not. Code logic is used to return what you need based on a match value.

Answer (score 2):

regex only:

```
string str = "abc";
```

length 3:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(str, "^.{3}$") ? "abc" : "xyz";
```

"abc":

```
return Regex.IsMatch(str, "^abc$") ? "abc" : "xyz";
```

Comment: For 3 or less you can use `^.{0,3}$`

Comment: the requirement was exactly 3 characters **"if input string length is 3"**

Comment: the input string is 3 or 5 characters

Comment: @VijayMothukuri that wasn't defined in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you ever wanted to do somethig like

```
string str="abc"

if(str=="abc") // or str.Lenght == 3
  return str;  // return original string
else
  return "xyz"
```

you could do it with only `Regex.Replace`

```
var ifNot = "xyz";
var testStrings = new []{"abc", "abcd", "ab", "123"};

var pattern = "^abc$"; // not 3 
    foreach( var s in testStrings)
        Console.WriteLine($"{s} => {Regex.Replace(s, pattern, ifNot)}");     

pattern = "^(.{0,2}|.{4,})$"; // not 3 
foreach( var s in testStrings)
    Console.WriteLine($"{s} => {Regex.Replace(s, pattern, ifNot)}");
```

### Output

```
abc => xyz
abcd => abcd
ab => ab
123 => 123
abc => abc
abcd => xyz
ab => xyz
123 => 123
```